# Swift error toggleAutomaticTextCompletion is only available in macOS 10.12.2 or newer

Tags: swift

I am getting the following error with the code below. I don't want to use the @ available. Is there any alternative or or way to code this that supports macOS 10.12

```
'toggleAutomaticTextCompletion' is only available in macOS 10.12.2 or newer
```

```
case .textCompletion:
                return (
                    #selector(NSTextView.toggleAutomaticTextCompletion(_:)),
                    .none
                )
```

Comment: You can use `if #available` instead and return some other selector when running on a system that doesn't support the newer API.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, isn't it? Whether you want to use #available or not is of no interest to the compiler whatsoever.

Comment: I can return another selector but just trying to figure out is there any alternative to replace it with.